# Whether PIR sensor hc-sr501 supported by ros

Tags: ros, arduino, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can any one send the Arduino Ros code for detecting humans using Pir sensor.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250705/whether-pir-sensor-hc-sr501-supported-by-ros/) by [anadgopi1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/28124/anadgopi1994/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-12-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, passive infrared sensor are not specifically detecting humans, but generally a moving heat source.
Second, this is probably the wrong place for this question as reading ADC inputs on an Arduino (AVR) is a hardware specific question. Generally you want to:

1. Find on how to read the sensor from your microcontroller (read the datasheets!)  Also there are probably tons of examples on the internet.
2. When you get to the point where your arduino/pir works and you want to integrate it with ROS check [rosserial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials)

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-12-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1